Count number of unique field in the input xml
I want to get no of unique "id" fields of below xml.
<jsonObject>
    <headers>
        <Resources>
            <field1>test-profile order 11</field1>
            <id>abca7923-eaea-4e9c-a952-b4aadc39a295</id>
            <description1>This is a test profile</description1>
        ...
        </Resources>
        <Resources>
            <field1>test-profile order 11</field1>
            <id>abca7923-eaea-4e9c-a952-b4aadc39a295</id>
            <description1>This is a test profile</description1>
            ...
        </Resources>
        <Resources>
            <field1>test-profile order 11</field1>
            <id>abca7923-eaea-4e9c-a952-b4aadc39a296</id>
            <description1>This is a test profile</description1>
            ...
        </Resources>
        <Resources>
            <field1>test-profile order 11</field1>
            <id>abca7923-eaea-4e9c-a952-b4aadc39a296</id>
            <description1>This is a test profile</description1>
            ...
        </Resources>
</headers>
</jsonObject>

I tried to get the unique "id" using the below xslt.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:key name="profileGroup" match="Resources" use="profileId" />

<xsl:template match="/jsonObject/headers">
    <jsonObject>
        <total>

            <xsl:for-each select="//id[not(.=preceding::id)]">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(//id[.=current()])" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </total>


    </jsonObject>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

But this is not working. I got this response. <total>22</total>
But I'm expecting this response <total>2</total>
What is the issue in my xslt?

If you are limited to XSLT 1.0 then use the Muenchian method to get distinct values (or, if your processor supports it, the EXSLT set:distinct() extension function).

I can use XSLT 2.0 also.

Just FYI, the answer you are getting <total>22</total> is not the number 22. It is the number 2 repeated twice.  Each unique id counts the number of ids (including itself) that are equal to itself.  You could have received the correct answer (albeit very inefficiently) using only <xsl:value-of select="count(//id[not(.=preceding::id)])" /> without xsl:for-each.

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can do simply:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/jsonObject">
    <jsonObject>
        <total>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(distinct-values(headers/Resources/id))" />
        </total>
    </jsonObject>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


In XSLT 1.0 you would use the first step of Muenchian grouping to get distinct values:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="res-by-id" match="Resources" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="/jsonObject">
    <jsonObject>
        <total>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(headers/Resources[count(. | key('res-by-id', id)[1]) = 1])"/>
        </total>
    </jsonObject>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

